# Prind index of 2D Array using the click event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

The code below display the index of each button when clicked the buttons are in an array but all this is done in form load. But I want to do the same thing in the click event and not in the form load how would I go about on doing this:

Image:[image]

Code:

```
namespace _2DArray
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button[,] b;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            b = new Button[2, 2];
            b = new Button[,] { {button1,button2 }, 
                                {button3, button4}};
        }
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 0;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button bt in b)
            {
                bt.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickedButton);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    b[i, j].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickedButton);
                    b[i, j].Name = "X: " + i + " " + "Y: " + j;

                }
            }

        }
        private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = (Button)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("you have clicked button: " + s.Name);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain _exactly_ what you mean by `pointer` - the traditional meaning is not the same as what you are talking about.

Comment: @Oded I have updated the question.. But I think its clear what I'm asking for

Comment: You can get X index with `int.Parse (s.Name.Split (" ")[1])` and Y with `int.Parse (s.Name.Split (" ")[3])` if that is what you want.

Comment: For me, it is still not clear what you are asking...

Comment: i just want to display the index of the button when i click it. but I want this in the clickevent not form load like i have it already

Comment: @Tacit you already do it in click event. In form_load you only assign event handlers.

Comment: But I'm having trouble using those values else where.. Ok now i know its hard to understand what i mean

Comment: Solved like this: int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[1]) thanks @Aleksandar

Answer (score 0):

Answered like so:

```
 private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = (Button)sender;
            int x = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[1]);
            int y = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[3]);

            MessageBox.Show("you have clicked button: " + x +" "+ y);
        }
```